# Очистить массив ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> из памяти

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я очищаю глобальные массивы из памяти, и надо ли это вообще делать?

```
//уничтожение(обнуление) массивов, особенно самого большого
public void kill_array_of_gallery() {
    if( galleries != null) {
        galleries.clear();
        galleries = null;
    }
    if( n_map_img_arrList != null) {
        n_map_img_arrList.clear();
        n_map_img_arrList = null;
    }
    if( mapsActivity.fr_Gallery_2.load_imgName_arrList != null) {
        mapsActivity.fr_Gallery_2.load_imgName_arrList.clear();
        mapsActivity.fr_Gallery_2.load_imgName_arrList = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: присваивать null не надо система сама все почистит, если на объект не будет ссылок

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут два варианта, либо очистить список, либо присвоить ссылке на список значение `null`.

- В первом случае, если *"достижимые"* объекты не содержат ссылки на
  объекты содержащиеся в массиве, garbage collector (GC) удалит эти
  объекты;
- Во втором случае, если *"достижимые"* объекты не содержат ссылки на
  этот список, GC удалит этот список, но не удалит объекты которые
  могли храниться в этом списке, если на них есть ссылки из
  "достижимых" объектов;

Как GC определяет *"достижимость"* объектов? С его точки зрения, объект считается достижимым, если до него можно добраться из GC roots. GC roots - это особые места, такие как классы стандартной библиотеки, локальные переменные, статические переменные, JNI ссылки и пр. Более подробно про это можете почитать [здесь](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/)

Касательно вашего вопроса, достаточно просто вызвать `clear()`